# How override the json view with reference objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My event model has this method to override the json view for fullcalender.

```
def as_json(options = {})
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :title => self.title,
      :slug => self.slug,
      :description => self.description || "",
      :start => starts_at.rfc822,
      :end => ends_at.rfc822,
      :allDay => self.all_day,
      :recurring => false,
      :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id)
    }

  end
```

My relationships are:

```
class Event
    belongs_to: city
    end

class City
    belongs_to: region
    has_many: events

    end

class Region
    has_many: cities
    end
```

Contoller

```
def index   
    @region = Region.find(1)
    @cities = @region.cities
    # full_calendar will hit the index method with query parameters
    # 'start' and 'end' in order to filter the results for the
    # appropriate month/week/day.  It should be possiblt to change
    # this to be starts_at and ends_at to match rails conventions.
    # I'll eventually do that to make the demo a little cleaner.
    @events = Event.scoped  
    @events = @events.after(params['start']) if (params['start'])
    @events = @events.before(params['end']) if (params['end'])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @events }
      format.js  { render :json => @events }
    end
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.xml
  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @event }
      format.js { render :json => @event.to_json }
    end
  end
```

The correct url/path is a nested resources (region_city_event).  How can I grab the region and city value and place them in the :url so the url is correct and nested?

Comment: You'll need to show us your controller & view code as to where you want to achieve this. In short, the page with the calendar must have the context of the region & city to pass through. If you just want to show all events, not caring about the region and city, then create another route to support it.

Comment: just updated question with contoller logic

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so since the index action is where you are responding with the json of events, you need to use the same link helper in the javascript code that you use to link users to the index html page.

In your view, you can just have something like this:

```
<script>
  var calendar_url = '<%= regions_cities_events_path(@region, @city) %>'
</script>
```

You'll need to add the following line to your index action in the events controller:

```
@city = City.find params[:city_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well you want to map '/region/city/event_id' to your events controller show action - to do that add this route to routes.rb:

```
match '/:region_id/:city_id/:event_id' => 'events#show'
```

Then in your show method in EventsController you can use `params[:region_id]` and `params[:city_id]` to find the region and city the user was looking for.

Comment: my routes is this...resources :regions do 
  resources :cities do
  resources :events  
  resources :restaurants
ect and i can use this region_city_event_path. So i gues i need to change the path of  :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id) to 
 :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.region_city_event_path(region, city, id)  But this wil not work!